# Property for comparing two composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we have two composition series
$$
 M = M_0 \unrhd M_1 \unrhd \cdots \unrhd M_r = 1
$$
and
$$
 M = N_0 \unrhd N_1 \unrhd \cdots \unrhd N_s = 1
$$
for a finite group $M$. Then we know that $r = s$. But for given $i$, let $j$ be choosen such that
$$
 M_{i-1} \cap N_j \le M_i, \quad\mbox{but}\quad M_{i-1} \cap N_{j-1} \nleq M_i.
$$

> How to show that $N_{j-1} \cap M_i \le N_j$?

As 
\begin{align*}
 N_{j-1} \cap M_{i-1} \le N_j 
 \Leftrightarrow N_{j-1} \cap M_{i-1} & = (N_{j-1} \cap M_{i-1}) \cap N_j \\
 & = M_{i-1} \cap N_j \\
 & \le M_i
\end{align*}
which is excluded, we must have $N_{j-1} \cap M_{i-1} \nleq N_j$. So if we choose $k$ such that
$$
 N_{k-1} \cap M_i \le N_k, \quad\mbox{but}\quad N_k \cap M_{i-1} \nleq N_k
$$
i.e. I guess as both conditions are a maximality requirement for $k$ we then must have $k \le j$. Just for sets these inclusion do not hold, so I guess there must be facts about groups and composition series involved, but I am unable to find the right argument. So I am asking for any help!?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the use of indices here. Should it be something like $M_{i+1} \cap N_j \leq M_i$?

Comment: No, its meant with respect to the subnormal series, where ascending indices correspond to descending subgroups. This is how it is written in my reference, but for example on wikipedia they write it the other way, i.e. lower indices correspond to smaller subgroups, maybe that is where some confusion might come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid all those suffixes, we have simple subnormal sections $A/B$ and $C/D$ of $G$ with $A \cap D \le B$ and $A \cap C \not\le B$, and we want to prove $B \cap C \le D$.

By the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem $(A \cap C)/(A \cap D) \cong (A \cap C)D/D \le C/D$, and since this quotient is nontrivial, $C/D$ is simple, and $A$ is subnormal in $G$, we have $(A \cap C)D = C$ and $(A \cap C)/(A \cap D)$ is simple.

Now $A \cap D = B \cap D \unlhd B \cap C \unlhd A \cap C$. But we know that $B \cap C \ne A \cap C$, so $B \cap D = B \cap C$ and the resut follows.